# Help to prove fact about Galois Theory?

Tags: galois-theory

If E is extension field over L, and L is field extension over F how to prove Gal(E/L) is a subgroup of Gal(E/F)? Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $G(E/L)$ is a subgroup of $G(E/F)$, note that any $L$-automorphism of $E$ is also an $F$-automorphism of $E$, since $F \subset L$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma\in Gal(E/L)$. Then $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $E$ fixing the elements of $L$. Since $F\subset L$, $\sigma$ fixes the elements of $F$ hence $\sigma \in Gal(E/F)$.

Comment: The inclusions get reversed: check the definitions, and you’ll see that it works out that way.